# why spyder 3 don't let me run these program?

Tags: python, spyder

here is my code... guess I need your help guys. I want to do some calculus

```
def moyenne(x):
    A=0
    for i in range (len(x)):
        A+= x[i]
    return (A/float(len(x))

def variance(x): #here spyder don't let me run the program and I don't know why...
    A= moyenne(x)
    Xs=0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        Xs+=(x[i]-A)**2
    return Xs/len(x)
```

Comment: What does _don't let me run the program_ mean, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error of unbalanced parenthesis in line 5.

return (A/float(len(x))

Should be

return (A/float(len(x)))

Comment: Or rather `return A/float(len(x))`.

Comment: thanks men... I'm a beginner so i still make a lot of mistake...